# Animate multiple views using the same Animation

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

I have a simple animator file:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:ordering="sequentially" >
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:valueTo="-50"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

Basically this takes a component and slides it along the X-axis by 50dp to the left. I've successfully attached this to ONE component, and it works flawlessly, but when I try to attach it to multiple components at once, the animation only works for the final component.

For Example:
I have 5 cards. The AI enemy picks a random card from it's hand. But I would like to animate the enemy "picking" the card. This is where the animation comes into play.

**So something like this**:

```
AnimatorSet cardSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.pick_card);

for(int i=0; i<enemyCards.size(); i++){
   cardSet.setTarget(enemyCards.get(i));
   cardSet.start();    
}
```

The goal here, would be to loop through each card in the array and slide it out on the X axis. But the animation only occurs on the final card (the 5th card in the array)

**Additionally** (*THIS IS BOLD FOR A REASON, people do not read large paragraphs anymore, and someone keeps editing my formatting*) - I would like to have a delay each time the card slides out. So the loop should be something like:

```
loop{
    animate card 1
    delay
}
```

OR

the animator file should be something like

```
android:delay="100"
```

Ive been trying with little success

Answer (score 1):

You can collect your views in some viewgroup and than animate just parent view so all child views animated ?

Answer (score 1):

This a sketch code written in text editor, it may have syntax errors, but you'll get the concept:

```
AnimatorSet cardSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.anim.pick_card);

List<AnimatorSet> animators = new ArrayList<>(enemyCards.size());

for (int i = 0, size = animators.size(); i < size; ++i) {
    animators.add(cardSet.clone());
}

final int step = 100;
int delay = 0;

for (int i = 0, size = enemyCards.size(); i < size; ++i) {
    AnimatorSet set = animators.get(i);
    set.setTarget(enemyCards.get(i));
    set.setStartDelay(delay);
    delay += step;
    set.start();    
}
```